# Move onto next class with same name in Web Scraper

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

my idea is to build a marketplace scraper where I could find the items I like, in this particular case, cassettes, the problem is that when I `soup.find(attrs="NameOfTheClass")` ,

the print value stays the same as the top result, I want to view all the products that are on the page.

I've tried a while loop but it keeps returning the same top value.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

URL = 'https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ar/cassette#D[A:cassette]'


headers = {
    "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.113 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
try:
    while True:
        title = soup.find(attrs={'main-title'})
        price = soup.find(attrs=('price__fraction'))
        print(title,price)
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('done')
```

Comment: Has the answer worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the find_all method

it shuld return a list of all elements with that class.
then you can iterate over that list

Answer (score 0):

*Try working with CSS selector*

*Example*

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ar/cassette#D[A:cassette]'

headers = {
    "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/81.0.4044.113 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

span = soup.select("span.main-title")
div = soup.select("div.price__container")


def get_title_and_price(span, div):
    for i, item in enumerate(span):
        title = item.getText()
        price = div[i].getText()
        print(title)
        print(price)


get_title_and_price(span, div)
```